# Change post title but not in widgets/menu/etc

Tags: title

I have searched and searched, and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I am using a shortcode and custom field to edit the title of a post by adding an audio player right behind the title. At first I was using "is_single" and that was working, however it changes the title in widgets too.

So I tried to use "in_the_loop" in the code, but then nothing shows up, so I'm clearly doing something wrong. This may be because I'm piecing together multiple pieces of code I found to get this working.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'se385007_title_filter' , 20, 2  );
function se385007_title_filter( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    if ( in_the_loop()){

    $termp = get_post_meta($post_id, "term_pronunciation", true);
        if($termp != ""){ $title .= "&nbsp; [sc_embed_player fileurl=\"" . $termp . "\"]"; }
        
    }
    return do_shortcode( $title ); 
    
}
```

Comment: `in_the_loop` only works inside the main post loop, but if all your pages are templates that discard the main query and create new ones via `WP_Query` then you are never in the loop, even if the custom query is what displays your main content. And if your page is rendered using page builder plugins then nobody will be able to answer this without page builder specific answers that would be off topic here. Rather than asking how to implement your filter though, maybe you should ask how to append a shortcode to your titles? There are very likely methods to do this that don't involve `the_title`

Comment: For example, adding it to the beginning of the content with custom styling, or modifying the template itself. The `the_title` filter is used in a lot of places, not just when displaying headings in widgets or the page, it's in RSS, XMLRPC, REST API, the title tag in the header, etc.

Comment: Many themes will have a hook built in on single page templates for something just like this.  If they don't just edit that template and add your code there.